# Scoping issue when adding multiple instances of views using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm hitting a scoping issue when using the ng-repeat functionality of AngularJS.

please see the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgZwstgDxJWdA7LvU3A4)

I have an array of objects 'boxCollection' and a list of items 'itemCollection' which I display in a drop down.

```
   $scope.boxCollection = [];

   $scope.itemCollection = 
      [
        {name: 'item1'},
        {name: 'item2'},
        {name: 'item3'}
      ];
```

Now I have my view as

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="addBox.html">
      <div class="box-controls">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-left" ng-click="addBox()"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-left" ng-class="{disable_div:boxCollection.length < 2} " ng-click="removeBox($index)"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-details">

          <div class="boxItem">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Item</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.name for item in itemCollection" ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item" ng-disabled="false">
                    <option value=""> None </option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class=" form-group ">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Item Desc</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text " class="form-control " ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item.desc ">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix "></div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

The view is wrapped in a script tag with an id and is called with an ng-repeat.

I have one function to add a box element into my view 'addBox()'. It generates one entry in 'boxCollection' array and another entry in 'boxTmplList' array. 'boxTmplList' is responsible for showing the views.

Now if you select let's say 'item1' from the drop down in box1 and add a value in the input field, add another box in the view using the '+' button and select 'item1' again in the another instance. It displays the value of input field 1 in the input field 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1Ii.png)

On further analysis I found that Angular tracks the objects with similar 'item' name using the same $hashkey.

I'm using a workaround by adding another property to the object 'boxCollection[$index].itemDesc' instead of 'boxCollection[$index].item.desc' and then later on modify the object using another function, but I feel that's not the most efficient way.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to stop updating input value in newly created item?

Comment: @Khalid - yes that's exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item"` to `ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item.name"` ,  like as-

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.name for item in itemCollection" ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item.name" ng-disabled="false">
```

Comment: @rsingh100 if it is working, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSIcbxOvqR4iSNOTUz8L?p=preview)

Change `ng-model="boxCollection[$index].item.desc"` to `ng-model="itemCollection[$index].name"`.

```
           <div class=" form-group ">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Item Desc</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text " class="form-control " ng-model="itemCollection[$index].name">
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: This will work Khalid, but I wanted to keep the item object.